# Async request issue in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a grid which displays customer records with paging. And I have one button called export all customers. While clicking on that button large amount of data will be exported and after that, I call paging. It is taking too much time beacuse of first request is not yet served.

I have created method for Async Method Export

```
public async Task<JsonResult> ExportDataExcel() {
    string ClientID = (String)Session["ClientID"];
    ConfigurationModel _configModel = new ConfigurationModel();
    string strConnection = _configModel.GetConnectionString(ClientID);

    string filename = string.Empty;

    using (ExportOrderService _exportService = new ExportOrderService(strConnection))
    {
        filename = await _exportService.generateUnshippedOrderExcel(ClientID);
    }

    return new JsonResult() { Data = new { FileName = filename } };
}
```

So when i click on paging it takes too much time, because first request is pending it shows. how can i achieve parallel execution.

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: Can you provide more information about your async call to the action from the client? Also, can you see both requests being executed in the browser Developer Tools, or does it wait for the first call to complete?

Comment: sending request using jQuery ajax,
Yes i have checked in developer tools second request is waiting untill first request is completed.